# Sudo: Using arguments in /etc/sudoers.d/ file, particularly with mount (visudo rejects syntax)

Tags: centos7, sudo, rhel7

I have a syntax wrangling problem with `sudo` that may not be solvable.

I know I know, OpenBSD's new `doas` is better than `sudo`, but it is not available on CentOS 7 *or* Rocky 8. So we're stuck with `sudo` for a while, girls and guys.

If I add the following line with `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/custom` it works, and `visudo` doesn't complain about it:

```
%group@domain.com *=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount -a
```

However, if I then add the following:

```
%group@domain.com *=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount -o remount,rw nfs-server.domain.com:/nfs3 /mnt/nfs3
```

Then `visudo` consistently rejects it with:
`syntax error near line 41`  (indeed it is line 41). I have tried various alternations of the above.

Any ideas why, or what would work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to read `man sudoers` as apparently some characters need escaping. Curiously the humble comma is one of them (not usually a sensitive character).

Extract:

```
 Note that the following characters must be escaped with a ‘\’
 if they are used in command arguments: ‘,’, ‘:’, ‘=’, ‘\’.
```

Comment: The comma is how you separate a list of commands, it seems reasonable that it should be escaped to not mean that you're starting a new command to allow...